# Двойные и одинарные кавычки

Tags: java, синтаксис

Не нашёл ответ в инете:
почему в Java двойные кавычки используются только для строк , а одинарные только для символов?
В чём профит?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Профит в том, чтобы чётко различать литералы строк и символов. Если бы и строки,  и символы можно было задавать с помощью одного и того же типа кавычек, то пришлось бв проверять, символ ли это, или строка. Иногда это вносило бы путаницу, а иногда точно определить это не представлялось бы возможным. Вот пример:

```
public void doSth(String s) {}

public void doSth(char c) {}

doSth("a");
```

Если бы литералы символов можно было задавать с помощью двойных кавычек, тут возникла бы неопределённость: какой метод вызывать?

Comment: просто скопировали подобное поведение с с/с++.